# What's the impact of sequence between cookies and session when implementing "current_user"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, session-cookies

I am learning how to build a simple authentication function with session and cookies.
I have a `User` model, then `sessions_controller`. I also create `remember_token` column for users table to handle the "remember_me" situation.
This is the relevant code:

---

**sessions_controller**

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    if params[:remember_me]
      user.generate_token(:remember_token)
      cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    end
    redirect_to root_url
    flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
  else
    render "new"
    flash[:notice] = "Invaid email or password."
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
has_secure_password

def generate_token(column)
  self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  self.save
end
```

**application_controller**

```
helper_method :current_user

def current_user
  if session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  elsif cookies[:remember_token]
    @current_user ||= User.find(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
end
```

---

The code above seems to be working. But at first I actually reversed the code's sequence in `:current_user`, like this:

```
def current_user
  if cookies[:remember_token]
    @current_user ||= User.find(cookies[:remember_token])
  elsif session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

This will raise an exception: "Couldn't find User with 'id'= some_token_here"

**In this case, why I can't use the cookies[:remember_token] to find the user firstly. Does the sequence matter? Or, if I had some misunderstanding about how session and cookies work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because if you use `find`, it finds a record by its database id.

What you want is to find by the `remember_token` column, so `User.find_by(remember_token: cookies[:remember_token])`

```
def current_user
  if cookies[:remember_token]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: cookies[:remember_token])
  elsif session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Robin van Dijk! That's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

[From Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

> Using the find method, you can retrieve the object corresponding to the specified primary key that matches any supplied options.

For example:

```
# Find the client with primary key (id) 10.
client = Client.find(10)
# => #<Client id: 10, first_name: "Ryan">
```

> User.find(session[:user_id]) returns all users that has matching primary_key
>
> In your second case: "User.find(cookies[:remember_token])", you should
>   search from "remember_token" column.

Comment: I'm ruminating all my questions and I found your explanation is also helpful, so thanks! @Omurbek.